# How to query photos/files by album using Drive REST API V3

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to query Drive files from the photos space using the REST API **by album**. I don't see my album names in any of the listed fields when I query the files, so I'm not sure what to filter q on.
I'm currently querying with the rest API like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?spaces=photos&fields=files
```

This returns a list of fields. None of which contain any names of my albums (some are in Google Photos albums, some not). If any did I would just add `&q=[field=value]` to the query string. So I'm not sure if this is possible and I'm not finding any information on how to go about it at all.

If it is possible, how?

Comment: Please add whatever methods / code you've already tried.

Comment: I haven't tried much of anything; I can't find any information about it or if it's even possible. If I had an idea of what to try, I would try it.

Answer (score 1):

In https://photos.google.com/settings enable "Google Drive Show Google Drive photos & videos in your Photos library"

In your files.list, you need a `spaces=photos`

Comment: sorry, I'm an idiot. I Idid have spaces=photos, I just typed it wrong in my question. Corrected now.

Comment: spaces=photos seems to give all photos on a Google Photos account. I have not found a solution to this problem either because no album ids are returned. I am able to get an object of album ids from the Google Picker, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the photos from those albums specifically. q='ALBUM_ID' in parents returns 404